# Why automatical deriving for newtype does not work

Tags: haskell, deriving

I use library [msgpack-types-0.0.4](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/msgpack-types-0.0.4) and I have a type:

```hs
newtype A = A Text
```

and I tried `deriving MessagePack`, `deriving newtype MessagePack`, standalone derivings, it seems nothing works (or I do something wrong). There is `MessagePack` instances for `Text`, for `String`, I thought that `newtype` deriving works always... Is it possible to derive this instance automatically? Why does not it work with `newtype` deriving?

EDIT:

An error message:

for `newtype A = A Text deriving newtype MessagePack`:

```
• Couldn't match representation of type ‘m Text’ with that of ‘m A’
    arising from the coercion of the method ‘fromObject’
      from type ‘forall (m :: * -> *).
                 (Applicative m, Monad m, MonadFail m) =>
                 Data.MessagePack.Object -> m Text’
        to type ‘forall (m :: * -> *).
                 (Applicative m, Monad m, MonadFail m) =>
                 Data.MessagePack.Object -> m A’
  NB: We cannot know what roles the parameters to ‘m’ have;
    we must assume that the role is nominal
• When deriving the instance for (MessagePack A)
```

Comment: Please include the error messages in your question.

Comment: See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776924/newtype-deriving-issequence)

Comment: Use `deriving anyclass` for those, or just plain empty instances.

Comment: Under normal circumstances given a class with generic default methods you should be able to use both `newtype` and `anyclass` deriving. `newtype` reuses `MessagePack Text` while `anyclass` uses the default methods which usually (as in this case) require `deriving stock Generic`. There is however a technical reason why `newtype` fails: it a deriving strategy that is `coerce`-based and we have no idea if it's safe to `coerce` under `m` in the type of `fromObject`. `m` is quantified from within the method so we can't constraint it. Same problem prevents us from deriving `Traversable`.

Comment: I tried to add `Generic` and to switch from `data` back to `newtype` and `deriving anyclass` works (it works with `data ...` as well). But `deriving newtype` still does not work with the same error. I have feeling that @Noughtmare reference is relevant and maybe the explanation of the problem. So yes, it's not coercible in a safe way. Thanks for answers

Comment: It's off topic but this affects many classes (Traversable and optics, Distributive ArrowApply Data MonadLogic..) and prevents others (Representable) from evolving. [Deriving `Traversable` has no local, BC solution](https://ryanglscott.github.io/2018/06/22/quantifiedconstraints-and-the-trouble-with-traversable/). That inspired [splitting a class into a backend](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/pqhivm/type_class_backend_how_to_evolve_with_class/) that is suitable for deriving (`fromObject :: Monad m => Object -> Yoneda m a`) and a user-facing frontend (`Monad m => Object -> m a`).